# zend 2 including custom library old style

Tags: zend-framework2

I have custom libs in old style zend. I mean:

/home/my/libs/StandardTypes/UF.php

```
class StandardTypes_UF{
  ...
}
```

I've tried use this in Zend 2

I tried this codes:

//init_autoloader.php

```
...
include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
    Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'autoregister_zf'   => true,
            'prefixes'          => array(
                'StantardTypes' => '/home/my/libs/StandardTypes',
            ),
        )
    ));
...
```

//controller

```
$st = new \StantardTypes_UF();
```

I have this error: Fatal error: Class 'Beneficio\Controller\StantardTypes_UF' not found

I tried this way too:

//Module.php

```
...
public function getAutoloaderConfig(){
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__   => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
                'prefixes' => array(
                    'StantardTypes' => '/home/my/libs/StandardTypes',
                ),              
            ),
        );
    }
...
```

I have the same error.

I cant change the libs to new style, first cuz it is too big, secund cuz it's used in old projects too.

Any ideia how to solve this?

Comment: Is your library without namespace ?

Comment: Do you try to call `new \StantardTypes\StantardTypes_UF()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I can't use a path out of the project. I put the lib StandardTypes in vendor path and it works!

```
...
'prefixes' => array(
  'StantardTypes' => '/home/my/project/vendor/StandardTypes',
 ), 
....
```